# How to disable the Android text highlighter for buttons?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm currently developing an app displaying the default android buttons:

**Screenshot**

[image: screenshot]

**Why is that little blue mark (i don't know the correct name) showing in my app?**

This is how I make it visible: I hold the button and then swipe from right to left over the text until the marker appears.

Usually I get that marker in EditText when selecting text - However this is a button and no EditText!

My XML for the button:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign in"
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainLin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in your XML :

```
android:textIsSelectable="false"
android:longClickable="false"
```

Comment: Sorry, but your solution doesn't work. I already had that setting turned off and it just visualizes where you touch when it's enabled. My text highlighter is showing when I highlight my text.

Comment: see the updated ansewer, if it doesn't work, please describe more